# HTML5 Deleting my drawings

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making a HTML5 grid with a rectangle select tool to be used on the grid.. It is going pretty good except when I try to use the rectangular select tool, my grid disappears. I want the grid to stay on the canvas.

Here is my code so far (you can probably better understand my problem if you test this),

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>

  <style type='text/css'>
    *
{
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}

html, body
{
    height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
canvas
{
    display: block;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(document).ready(function () {

    function renderGrid(x_size,y_size, color)
    {
        var canvas = $("#myCanvas").get(0);
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        context.save();
        context.lineWidth = 0.5;
        context.strokeStyle = color;

        // horizontal grid lines
        for(var i = 0; i <= canvas.height; i = i + x_size)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(0, i);
            context.lineTo(canvas.width, i);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }

        // vertical grid lines
        for(var j = 0; j <= canvas.width; j = j + y_size)
        {
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(j, 0);
            context.lineTo(j, canvas.height);
            context.closePath();
            context.stroke();
        }

        context.restore();
    }

    renderGrid(10,15, "gray");
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>

<div style="height:480px;width:640px;border:1px solid #ccc;font:16px/26px Georgia, Garamond, Serif;overflow:auto;">

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="border:0px solid #000000;">
Your browser does not support the HTML5 canvas tag.
</canvas>

</div>

<script>
// Keep everything in anonymous function, called on window load.
if(window.addEventListener) {
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var canvas, context;

  // The active tool instance.
  var tool;
  var tool_default = 'rect';

  function init () {
    // Find the canvas element.
    canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    if (!canvas) {
      alert('Error: I cannot find the canvas element!');
      return;
    }

    if (!canvas.getContext) {
      alert('Error: no canvas.getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Get the 2D canvas context.
    context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!context) {
      alert('Error: failed to getContext!');
      return;
    }

    // Activate the default tool.
    if (tools[tool_default]) {
      tool = new tools[tool_default]();
    }

    // Attach the mousedown, mousemove and mouseup event listeners.
    canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', ev_canvas, false);
    canvas.addEventListener('mouseup',   ev_canvas, false);
  }

  // The general-purpose event handler. This function just determines the mouse 
  // position relative to the canvas element.
  function ev_canvas (ev) {
    if (ev.layerX || ev.layerX == 0) { // Firefox
      ev._x = ev.layerX;
      ev._y = ev.layerY;
    } else if (ev.offsetX || ev.offsetX == 0) { // Opera
      ev._x = ev.offsetX;
      ev._y = ev.offsetY;
    }

    // Call the event handler of the tool.
    var func = tool[ev.type];
    if (func) {
      func(ev);
    }
  }

  // The event handler for any changes made to the tool selector.
  function ev_tool_change (ev) {
    if (tools[this.value]) {
      tool = new tools[this.value]();
    }
  }


  // This object holds the implementation of each drawing tool.
  var tools = {};

  // The rectangle tool.
  tools.rect = function () {
    var tool = this;
    this.started = false;

    this.mousedown = function (ev) {
      tool.started = true;
      tool.x0 = ev._x;
      tool.y0 = ev._y;
    };

    this.mousemove = function (ev) {
      if (!tool.started) {
        return;
      }

      var x = Math.min(ev._x,  tool.x0),
          y = Math.min(ev._y,  tool.y0),
          w = Math.abs(ev._x - tool.x0),
          h = Math.abs(ev._y - tool.y0);

      context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

      if (!w || !h) {
        return;
      }

      context.strokeRect(x, y, w, h);
    };

    this.mouseup = function (ev) {
      if (tool.started) {
        tool.mousemove(ev);
        tool.started = false;
      }
    };
  };

  init();

}, false); }
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

thanks, if you need more explanation please let me know.

Comment: Well your code calls `.clearRect()` on the whole canvas, so that'll wipe out the grid.

Comment: Hmm, but if I remove that, it doesn't erase the previous rectangle from the selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);` in your tool draw function which clears the entire canvas.

You have to add the call to `renderGrid` after the call to `clearRect` in order for the grid to be redrawn or change the structure slightly to have a draw function which calls `clearRect` `renderGrid` and any tools you have. Then in your listener you add the tool to your a list of tools to be drawn and call the draw function.

Comment: Is that the most efficient way? Rendering the grid  all the time seems like it wouldn't be the best idea. Do you know of some way to overlay the tool layer on the grid or something?

Comment: Well clearRect will clear the space that you specify. So if you don't want to redraw everything you can call clearRect on a certain area. That being said you would have to redraw that area of the grid. It depends on how many objects you have to draw but for a small games you shouldn't run into any issues with the complete redraw approach

Comment: You could also have 2 canvases. One to draw your grid with a style z-index of 1 and another for tools with a style z-index of 2. Just be sure to have a containing div and set the position to be absolute within the div.

Comment: @JasonM yes, that's what I'm thinking too - and since it's just a rectangle, it could also be a simple `<div>` with a border and transparent background

Comment: Ya it all depends on how much functionality is needed and if this is more for learning or just trying to achieve something.